# failed to load during JIRA startup. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/management/InstanceNotFoundException

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin

Current **Java** JDK version and home environment variable command line ouput:

```
D:\>set
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161
```

**How to fix error in my custom Jira plugin?**

I checked, Java SDK already contains this class, so it is strange issue.

j2ee 1.2.1 jar fixes startup, but breaks getConnection() call in Java code

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.management.MemoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.management.NotificationEmitter
```

Here is my whole root **POM** XML file content,

it contains only olugin skeleton and oracle, postgres, mysql, mssql and related dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.x.jira.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.x.jira.plugin-y</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <organization>
        <name>x</name>
        <url>https://www.x.co/</url>
    </organization>
    <name>com.x.jira.plugin-y</name>
    <description>This is the com.x.jira.plugin:com.x.jira.plugin-y plugin
        for Atlassian JIRA.</description>
    <packaging>atlassian-plugin</packaging>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>ora</id>
            <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jira.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.1-atlassian-hosted</version>
        </dependency>
                 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.ons</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.oracle.ons</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
                 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>oraclepki</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
                 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>orai18n</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.47</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0.jre8</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.aad</groupId>
    <artifactId>adal4j</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
    <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.1.2</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.9</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jy.jyas</groupId>
    <artifactId>jy-as-connector</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion><groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId></exclusion>
            </exclusions>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.20</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jira.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
             <exclusions>
 <exclusion>
 <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
 <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
 </exclusion>
 </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-annotation</artifactId>
            <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-plugins-osgi-testrunner</artifactId>
            <version>${plugin.testrunner.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2-atlassian-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugins.rest</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-rest-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.sal</groupId>
            <artifactId>sal-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wink</groupId>
            <artifactId>wink-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3-incubating</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
<groupId>org.jy.jyas</groupId>
<artifactId>jy-as-connector</artifactId><version>6.1.0.Final</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId></exclusion>
                </exclusions>
</dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jira.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
             <exclusions>
 <exclusion>
 <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
 <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
 </exclusion>
 </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
    <id>atlassian</id>
    <url>https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
     <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
         <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
 </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jira-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${amps.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <compressResources>false</compressResources>
                    <productVersion>${jira.version}</productVersion>
                    <productDataVersion>${jira.version}</productDataVersion>
                    <enableQuickReload>true</enableQuickReload>
                    <enableFastdev>false</enableFastdev>
                    <instructions>
                        <Atlassian-Plugin-Key>${atlassian.plugin.key}</Atlassian-Plugin-Key>
                        <Export-Package>com.x.jira.plugin.y.api,</Export-Package>
                        <Import-Package>org.springframework.osgi.*;resolution:="optional", org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.*;resolution:="optional", *</Import-Package>
                        <Spring-Context>*</Spring-Context>
                    </instructions>
<excludes>
<exclude>**/CertificateTest.class</exclude>
    <exclude>**/GetoptDemo.class</exclude>
    <exclude>**/KeyStoreTest.class</exclude>
    <exclude>CertificateTest.class</exclude>
    <exclude>GetoptDemo.class</exclude>
    <exclude>KeyStoreTest.class</exclude>
</excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>atlassian-spring-scanner</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scannedDependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-external-jar</artifactId>
                        </dependency>
                    </scannedDependencies>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <jira.version>7.12.0</jira.version>
        <amps.version>8.0.0-edfff1b</amps.version>
        <plugin.testrunner.version>1.2.3</plugin.testrunner.version>
        <atlassian.spring.scanner.version>1.2.13</atlassian.spring.scanner.version>
        <atlassian.plugin.key>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</atlassian.plugin.key>
        <testkit.version>6.3.11</testkit.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```